# How do I limit the concurrent number of readers in a first readers writers problem?

Tags: c, computer-science, semaphore

I would like to understand how implement some form of concurrency that would limit the number of readers.

```
void *reader(void *rno)
{   
    // Reader acquire the lock before modifying numreader
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    numreader++;
    if(numreader == 1) {
        sem_wait(&wrt); 
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    // Reading Section
    printf("Reader %d: read cnt as %d\n",*((int *)rno),cnt);

    // Reader acquire the lock before modifying numreader
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    numreader--;
    if(numreader == 0) {
        sem_post(&wrt);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

I've tried this, While this just enables all readers to run and calls the writers afterwards, I want to understand how to call a limited number of readers at a time, then, allow writers to run.

`wrt` is a binary semaphore but if it is a counting semaphore initialized to the limit, does this help in achieving the goal?

Comment: if `wrt` is a counting semaphore initialized to the limit, it should help you achieve the goal, yes. In fact, that is all you need, and there are actually parts of the code that need tot be deleted, if I'm not mistaken. The current code does not allow more than one reader to read at the same time, due to the use of `numreader`. I would delete all code relating to `numreader`, and leave only the `sem_wait`, the reading section, and the `sem_post`. Unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a counting semaphore with the count set to the max reader count can solve it. Below is a little Java code you can run to understand.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis;

class CountingSemaphore {
    private final int maxCount;
    private int signals = 0;

    public CountingSemaphore(int maxCount) {
        this.maxCount = maxCount;
    }

    public synchronized void take() throws InterruptedException {
        while (signals==this.maxCount) wait();
        this.signals++;
        this.notify();
    }

    public synchronized void release() throws InterruptedException{
        while(this.signals == 0) wait();
        this.signals--;
        this.notify();
    }

    public synchronized int getThreadCount(){
        return signals;
    }

}
class Reader{
    private final int id;

    public Reader(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void read(CountingSemaphore semaphore) throws InterruptedException {
        semaphore.take();

        System.out.printf("Reader %d is reading. Reader count is %d%n", id, semaphore.getThreadCount());
        semaphore.release();
    }
}

public class ConcurrentReaderTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        CountingSemaphore countingSemaphore = new CountingSemaphore(5);
        List<Thread> readerThreads = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            Reader reader = new Reader(i);
            readerThreads.add(new Thread(()-> {
                try {
                    reader.read(countingSemaphore);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }));
        }
        readerThreads.stream().forEach(r->r.start());
        long startTime = currentTimeMillis();
        readerThreads.stream().forEach(r->r.run());
        System.out.println("time taken: "+ String.valueOf(currentTimeMillis()-startTime));


    }
}
```